# How to create a simple WAR file with OSGI module

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jboss, osgi, war

I'm new to Web java programming. I want to create a simple JSF modular application. I found a simple tutorial [link](http://heapdump.wordpress.com/2010/03/25/osgi-enabled-war/)

but unfortunately I still have some questions how to use OSGI:

1. Can I create a simple OGI bundle and place in it some JSF pages? If not how usually web applications are developed.
2. Can you give me link with example how I can call functions and pass arguments form a WAR file to OSGI module.

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not an answer specifically for JSF ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575669/how-to-modularize-a-jsf-facelets-spring-application-with-osgi) might be), but for OSGi web-apps in general take a look at [Pax-Web](http://team.ops4j.org/wiki/display/paxweb/Pax+Web) if you're using [maven](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html).

The easiest way to get started with [Pax-Web](http://team.ops4j.org/wiki/display/paxweb/Pax+Web) is probably to use [Karaf](http://karaf.apache.org/) and then run the command `features:install war`

Once a WAR (or WAB - Web App Bundle) is deployed you'll be able to use the 
**osgi-bundlecontext** attribute in Servlet initialization, eg:

```
extends HttpServlet {

BundleContext bundleContext;

@Override
public void init() throws ServletException
{
    bundleContext = (BundleContext) getServletContext().getAttribute("osgi-bundlecontext");

}
```

Using this you can look up services in the OSGi registry.

You'll need to pay attention to the bundle's MANIFEST.MF entries, two in particular:

```
Bundle-ClassPath: ./,WEB-INF/classes
Webapp-Context: context-root-name-here
```

Or in an OSGi compliant WebApp container you'll need to add:

```
Web-ContextPath: context-root-name-here
```

There's more info in the [specifications](http://www.osgi.org/Specifications/HomePage), see the enterprise or compendium PDFs for [v4.2](http://www.osgi.org/Download/Release4V42)

**EDIT**: For deploying in JBoss you'll most likely want to use the WAB support, see section 128 of the enterprise 4.2 spec.   Also this may help: http://community.jboss.org/message/619443
Interestingly JBoss AS7 is using pax-web, so the documentation for this should largely apply too.

Comment: It turns out that I will use EAR packaging because I need to use resource adapter. Is above code compatible with EAR package?

Comment: I've edited my answer with some JBoss specific info, specifically you'll want to create a WAB (also added a link for maven-bundle-plugin)

Comment: One more question: I created a simple OSGI bundle which makes queries to database using datasource from JBoss 7.1.0. When I try to deploy it the JBoss 7.1.0 trows me an arror. Is it possible that this might be a bug in JBoss?

Comment: This is the error stack from JBoss when I try to deploy the OSGI bundle http://pastebin.com/XrCY6w5b

Comment: What for dependencies you are using for OSGI?